# Magento - How to set the order of the query as descending

Tags: sorting, magento-1.9, product-quantity

I have created a query that would allow me to sort my products based on the quantity they have been ordered. But when I print the query, the quantity ordered is coming in Ascending order. I want to make it work in descending order. The query is as below

```
$toDate =  date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime('tomorrow') - 1);
$fromDate = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime("-1 months"));
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoi' => $this
->getTable('sales/order_item')),
 "e.entity_id = sfoi.product_id AND sfoi.created_at BETWEEN 
 '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",                 
array('qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)'))
            ->group('e.entity_id')                   
            ->order("qty_ordered {$dir}");        
            return $this;
```

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this? I just want to change the order of "**qty_ordered**" From ASC to DESC

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `->order()` by

```php
->order('qty_ordered ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);
```

PS: Because you didn't show more of your code, I have no idea what your `$dir` variable is for. Maybe altering the variable will simply do the trick?